# How to Create a Report Containing 3 DataTables

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatables, reportviewer, rdlc

### Goal

I want to create a report that will contain three DataTables (unless doable with 1 DataTable, you tell me!). The following screenshot displays `ConveyorNames`, `OptionNames`, `ConveyorOptionPrices`:

[image: Report Pricing]

### Problem

The problem I am facing is I cannot seem to figure out how I will go about displaying horizontal conveyor Names (Conveyor1, Conveyor2, Conveyor3, ...) horizontally while displaying OptionNames (Optn1, Optn2, Optn3, ...) vertically; while at the same time populating the price for Conveyor1 and Optn1 (and so on) in their relative cells.

I'd like to provide something that I have tried, but nothing conclusive as of yet would be useful here. To be honest, I don't even know where to start. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using only 1 DataTable. You must create a Matrix and attach this DataTable to it.

Related to my example, my DataTable will contain the following fields: `ConveyorName`, `OptionName`, and `OptionPrice` like so:

[image: Matrix Example]

Afterwards, I just loop through my three DataTables and fill in the fields like so:

```
For Each convRow As ds1.dtConveyorsRow In dsConv.dtConveyors
    For Each optnRow As ds2.dtOptionsRow In dsOptn.dtOptions
        For Each convOptnRow As ds3.dtConvOptnsRow In dsConvOptn.dtConvOptns.Select("FK_Conveyor=" & convRow.PK_Conveyor & " AND FK_Option=" & optnRow.PK_Option)
            dtRpt.AddConvOptnRow(convRow.ConveyorName, optnRow.Name, convOptnRow.Price)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Which populates it exactly as I showed in my question's picture.